# Stream music as if it was a phone call

Tags: audio, calls, bluetooth-audio, streaming

I have a car that handles Bluetooth and that plays on the car speakers my phone calls, but doesn't play my music.

Would someone know a trick or an app that would simulate a phone call and redirect the music sound stream as it was the caller stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested a similar App 'Blue Mono sound' github & opensource. I connected the BT to my car, then launched the music, then this App. After playing with the sound volume I finally got the music on my car speakers. YAAATAAA! Thanks for your input

Answer (score 2):

I read that BTmono is an app that does that kind of thing, but I had no success using it in my car with a Galaxy S7 Edge.

Without any app, I noticed that sometimes after ending a call the car keeps hanging on the the BT stream allowing Google Map's navigation directions to be announced through the car speakers treating it like an in-call sound. But I'm guessing that's probably a bug with the software in the car's entertainment system.